# MacOS, files out of place?

Tags: macos

Somehow I've got a bunch of files in the trash that won't delete and report they are important to the OS.  I'd like to put them back where they below.   One of the files is     hp2392    Thank you

Comment: The specific report is that the files can't be deleted because of System Integrity Protection.   I'd like to put them back where they belong.   Thanks

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on them and choosing "Put Back", which should return them to their original location

Answer (score 1):

If you find them the same day...

Right click in the Trash > Put Back.

I think that only works for one day, otherwise you need to know where they came from.
*Edit:* Interestingly, I have a folder discarded 3 days ago that has a Put Back, but none of its contents do, so it might be more complicated than I first thought.